# How to append a custom angular directive into another custom angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two custom angular directives and one appends the second repeatedly. The problem is that although the tag is appended, the template of the directive is not. When I manually put it in, it works.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5555/

Here is the code where the appending takes place:

```
myApp.directive('formList', function () {
    return {
        template: '<my-form></my-form>',
        require:'^repeatableForm',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, repeatableFormCtrl) {
            scope.add = function () {
                console.log("test");
                element.append('appended <my-form></my-form>'); // apended<my-form></my-form> will appear but not the contents of <my-form>
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you are not meant to append directives unfortunately. You are meant to append HTML, or modify the current html/css. But since you are doing it this way, you might need to do a $compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$compile` service to manually compile your `my-form` directive like this:

```
myApp.directive('formList', function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: '<my-form></my-form>',
        require:'^repeatableForm',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, repeatableFormCtrl) {
            scope.add = function () {
                console.log("test");
                var newForm = $compile('<span>appended </span><my-form></my-form>')(scope);
                element.append(newForm);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Example JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9L3whcqc/